# Change font size of text in a table cell

Tags: tables, fontsize

I'm trying to create some beautoful tables with LaTex, but it's kind of hard.

How can I change the font size of only *some* words within a table cell?

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
text:&this is a text, and I only want two or three words to be smaller than the rest in THIS table cell!\\[1ex]
\end{tabularx}
```

Is it possible to change, for example for the words "this is a text" the font size to small?

`{\small this is a text}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following shows how to use `\small`, or `\tiny` to obtain smaller text:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
    text:&this is a text, and I only want two or three words to be 
    smaller than the rest in THIS table cell!
    {\color{blue}\small this is small text} and {\color{red}\tiny this is tiny text}\\[1ex]
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```