# Change font size within table

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    labelsep=newline
    }
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{A Stylish Table Header with Important Knowledge}}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\small\lipsum[1]\vspace{2ex}}
\medskip
%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                c
                S[table-format=-2.2]
                *{9}{S}
                }
\toprule
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2}&
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 3}\\
\cline{2-4}\cline{5-7}\cline{8-10}
{Pct}&{Sim}&{Act}&{Com}&{Sim}&{Act}&{Com}&{Sim}&{Act}&{Com}\\\midrule
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Panel A: Some text}\\\midrule
A   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
B   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
C   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
D   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
E   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
F   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
G   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
H   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
I   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
J   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
K   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
L   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
M   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
N   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
O   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
P   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
Q   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
R   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
S   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{10}{r}{\textit{(continued)}}\\
\end{tabular*}
%} % end of resizebox
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

which produces this table:

[image: table]

As shown in the picture, the header **Table I** and the bottom note *(continued)* are placed outside of the frame due to the table's size. Is it possible to resize (either manually or automatically) the font size only within the table?

I have already looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326863/automatically-choose-font-size-within-table) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83934/change-font-size-of-text-in-a-table-cell), and I know that my question is, at the very least, close to a duplicate.

However, I can't seem to make the answers from those questions work in my case. I tried to manually set the font size to small with `{\small ...}`, and I also tried the automatic approach with `\resizebox`. `\resizebox` was unable to include the **Table I** header within the frame, and I have noticed that many users on this site advise against this method.

Comment: Have you tried something like `\medskip
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular*}`? This will only change the fontsize until `\end{sidewaystable}`

Comment: @leandriis: Thank you again! This solves it exactly. Apparently, the solutions are often quite simple when it comes to LaTeX. Have a great day!

Comment: @leandriis: By the way, I can mark your solution as accepted, if you make a formal answer, if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use a smaller font size for the table only, you could insert the `\footnotesize` command just before `\begin{tabular}` as shown in the following MWE. That way, everything until `\end{sidewaystable}` will be in the smaller fontsize. If you want 'continued'  to be in normalsize instead, you can also use `\multicolumn{10}{r}{\normalsize\textit{(continued)}}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    labelsep=newline
    }
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{A Stylish Table Header with Important Knowledge}}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\small\lipsum[1]\vspace{2ex}}
\medskip
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                c
                S[table-format=-2.2]
                *{9}{S}
                }
\toprule
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2}&
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 3}\\
\cline{2-4}\cline{5-7}\cline{8-10}
{Pct}&{Sim}&{Act}&{Com}&{Sim}&{Act}&{Com}&{Sim}&{Act}&{Com}\\\midrule
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Panel A: Some text}\\\midrule
A   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
B   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
C   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
D   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
E   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
F   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
G   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
H   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
I   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
J   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
K   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
L   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
M   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
N   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
O   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
P   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
Q   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
R   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
S   &11.11  &22.22  &33.33  &44.44  &55.55  &66.66  &77.77  &88.88  &99.99\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{10}{r}{\textit{(continued)}}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I can use the normal size for the _(continue)_.